# Not able to perform virtual experiments in simulator without Adobe flash player

Tags: flash

I am a Physics teacher. I was using virtual lab simulation to teach Physics experiments which required adobe flash player. Now few days back I got a popup asking to uninstall Adobe flash player as it will no longer be supported after 31st December 2020. I did a bit of survey and found that if website makes the content compatible with html5 it will run. But what will happen to sites which wont update?
Here is the link of simulation which needs adobe flash player:
http://vlab.amrita.edu/?sub=1&brch=281&sim=1524&cnt=4

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The sites that won't update, won't work. You'll have to switch to alternate players like [Ruffle](https://ruffle.rs/#what-is-ruffle) or [NewGrounds](https://www.newgrounds.com/flash/player) (I haven't tried either) and hope that these would do the job